# CentOS Freeswitch v1.10 : No audio on a fresh installation

Tags: freeswitch

We did a fresh installation of Freeswtich v1.10 built from source. Have not changed any configuration except for setting the IP address of server in "external_rtp_ip" and "external_sip_ip" in vars.xml

When freeswitch is started, this is how the listeners look -

```
tcp        0      0 <SVR_IP>:5060        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10503/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 <SVR_IP>:8081        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10503/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 <SVR_IP>:8082        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10503/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8021         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10503/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 <SVR_IP>:5080        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10503/freeswitch
```

When we test between two sample IDs that are already available, there is an incoming ring, the call gets answered but no audio. The log is provided below.

```
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:3794 Channel [sofia/internal/1001@<SVR_IP>] has been answered
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3865 (sofia/internal/1001@<SVR_IP>) Callstate Change EARLY -> ACTIVE
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7326 Channel sofia/internal/1001@<SVR_IP> entering state [completed][200]
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3852 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/internal/1000@192.168.43.32:18486]
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3852 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/internal/1000@192.168.43.32:18486]
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1793 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.43.32:18486) State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA -> CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.43.32:18486) Running State Change CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA (Cur 2 Tot 6)
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:654 (sofia/internal/1000@192.168.43.32:18486) State EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2020-10-21 08:32:12.323087 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:656 SOFIA EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2020-10-21 08:32:12.723235 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7326 Channel sofia/internal/1001@<SVR_IP> entering state [ready][200]
2020-10-21 08:32:16.123236 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:2448 RTCP packet not written
2020-10-21 08:32:20.143147 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:2448 RTCP packet not written
2020-10-21 08:32:24.163187 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:2448 RTCP packet not written
```

The last line "RTCP packet not written" keeps repeating. Please let us know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an embarrassingly simple reason - the RTCP ports were not opened in the firewall. Once that was done, it worked fine.